# Refactoring controller methods that use the same service method, but each service method has to use a different value

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I have a controller with two methods A and B. Both methods call my service method getTasks(). The difference is that each method A and B requires a different value for constants.Project in getTasks().

getTasks:

```
private async List<Task> getTasks() {
   // logic...
    return constants.Project;
}
```

How should I refactor? Should I do something like this:

```
A() {
    return service.getTasks("A");
}

B() {
    return service.getTasks("B");
}

private async List<Task> getTasks(String param) {
       // logic...
        if(param == "A") {
            return constants.ProjectA;
        } 
        return constants.ProjectB;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `constants` a lookup, so you can query `constants["ProjectA"]` ? (Or similar, but you get the idea) => that would eliminate the need for `if / elseif / ...` or `switch`es.

Comment: You _may_ also be interested in: [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Refactor the logic into a private method, then return the specific constant in `A` and `B`. Don't introduce an unnecessary `if`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i want to retain getTasks() because I have similar situations where I am not returning constants.ProjectA, but rather just using it in the function

Comment: @Fildor if its a lookup then how does that eliminate the need for if/ else if?

Comment: _"how does that eliminate the need for if/ else if"_ you can directly index into it instead of asking "if its A then return o.A, else if it is B then return o.B ... " you just say "return o[whatever id was passed]".

Comment: Exactly how are you getting the list of tasks? Could they be pulled from somewhere based on a param or are you just cobbling together the list depending on what that param is?

Comment: @sr28 They cant just be pulled from somewhere based on a param. Yes the latter

Comment: @Sienna - is this the only service method that needs to know whether it's dealing with controller A or B? Also, is there any logic that decides what tasks each controller should get beyond whether they're A or B?

Comment: @sr28 there are other methods that need to know whether they're dealing with controller A or B so I am planning on passing the params throughout? The logic for getting tasks depending on whether they're A or B is in this service method (which calls one other service method)

Comment: If you have lots of methods that need to know whether it's coming from controller A or controller B, you might be better implementing an abstract service class and then creating 2 concrete service classes that deal with the separate implementations for controller A and B requirements.